# Not sure about the way to compute the voltage across a DC motor driven by a NPN BJT

Tags: bjt, dc-motor, speed

Long story short, I wanted to make my own H-bridge but I was out of p-channel MOSFETS so I tried to design one with BJTs instead, but before doing just that I simply wanted to try to run an average 3-6V DC motor with a NPN transistor with the following circuit (actual circuit on the left and the equivalent circuit on the right) :
[image: Actual circuit (left), equivalent circuit (right)]

It's just your average BJT power interface, nothing too much out of the ordinary around here.

I know that one can compute the base resistor as such : R1=(V1-Vbe)*Hfe/Ic, which is useful as it's common knowledge that, for a DC motor, the consumed current is proportional to the motor's torque and that the motor's speed is proportional to the voltage across it.
Thus, varrying the resistor value allows us to change the motor's maximum torque, which is great.

**But here is the thing, how can one compute the *voltage* across the motor without measuring its speed and by assuming there is a known torque applied to the motor ?**

I simply do not understand how it's done. With my quite limited knowledge of BJTs I have only measured voltage across resistive loads so far by simply making use of Ohm's law since I am able to calculate the collector current but in this case I must say that I have no idea as to how it's done, I can only make the assumption that the voltage across the motor will be between V1 and the CE saturation voltage but that's about it. I made some research on the topic but I can only seem to stumble across arduino tutorials not even mentioning the issue.

And before you ask, no I do not have the datasheet of the motor (I just want to understand the principle) and yes I know using a MOSFET in this speed-related case would be easier to implement as one can simply compute the motor's voltage with the help of the Rdson internal resistance, but again I want to understand this for education purposes only.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You're much better off using PWM to control the motor rather than trying to vary the base resistor of a BJT to control the current.  The beta of a BJT varies from unit to unit, over temperature, and with collector current.  Also operating in linear mode will dissipate lots of power.  You can use a current sense resistor and a control circuit to PWM the motor and control torque.  The duty cycle will give you an approximation of the average motor voltage.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks, but as I said I know this circuit in and itself isn't the easiest to implement nor is the most efficient, I just want to understand how *mathematically* is the voltage across the motor calculated for education purposes only. That's it.

Comment: If you have a motor with unknown load and unknown parameters and all you know is the current through it, you can't calculate the voltage across it.  You can measure it, or measure the shaft speed and estimate it, but that's about it.

Comment: @JohnD It may not have been explicitly clear but I mentioned that I looked for a way to compute this voltage by assuming *there is* a known load applied to the motor, otherwise I too can hardly see how that would be computable.

Comment: You're fixing the torque by forcing a current in your motor.  What you need is the torque/speed characteristic of your load to get the speed and estimate the voltage.

Comment: @JohnD Great, thank you.

Comment: To me, when I look at this circuit, I see an NPN which will probably be saturated. The rules of thumb would then mean that you have ~0.6V BE voltage and 0.3V CE voltage, so the voltage over the motor is 5V-0.3V = 4.7V. If the NPN is not saturated, god only knows that the voltage is because it's totally dependant on the beta of the transistor and R1, as @JohnD mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can one compute the voltage across the motor without measuring its
> speed **and by assuming there is a known torque applied to the motor** ?

In your circuit you can't. However if you know the motor's torque constant (Kt) you can calculate the current required to produce the 'known' torque. If the transistor can deliver more than that (ie. it is in saturation) then the motor will get the full supply voltage (less saturation voltage of the transistor). If the transistor cannot deliver the required current the motor will slow down and its voltage will drop until it stalls.

If the load torque is not constant but **increases with speed** then as the motor slows down a point may be reached where the current is sufficient to produce that torque. For example a propeller's torque is proportional to the square of speed, so if you know what the current is at one voltage you can calculate what the voltage will be at a different current.

On the other hand, a load whose torque **reduces at higher speed** will prevent the motor from starting if it doesn't get enough current, but race up to a higher speed if the current is sufficient to start it. As the motor speeds up its voltage increases, making it speed up even more until it reaches full voltage or the torque load increases to stabilize the speed. This makes your circuit a poor method of determining motor voltage. It may work OK for fans or fixed propellers which have a strongly positive torque to rpm relationship, but not for other things like compressors or traction motors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed and clear explanation!